Failed to load database information when using Crystal Report Export to PDF
I upgraded a VB.Net winform application from framework 1.1 to 4.8 and it has Crystal Report for Visual Studio. I have referenced Crystal Decisions dll. When trying to Export the report to PDF, I am getting following error :
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException: 
   'Error in File temp_2c6ba400-c64b-4149-8bfa-809476a7034f 
    5440_26204_{EEF115AD-3134-4437-AA42-EAE286E956B2}.rpt:
    Failed to load database information.'

These are the referenced dlls in my project.

Here is the code :
    Private Sub ExportReport(ByVal lvi As ListViewItem)
    '
    ' Define variables.
    '
    Dim ci As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim DiskFileOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions
    Dim ExportOptions As New ExportOptions
    Dim logon As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim rpt As New ReportDocument
    Dim tbl As Table
    '
    ' Initalize variables.
    '
    Try
        rpt = listViewItem.Tag // the selected item in LV
        '
        ' Set connection information.
        '
        ci = rpt.Database.Tables(0).LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo
        ci.DatabaseName = DatabaseConnection.Path + "\MyFile.mdb"
        ci.ServerName = ""
        ci.UserID = "Admin"
        ci.Password = ""
        '
        ' Set table logon information.
        '
        For Each tbl In rpt.Database.Tables
            logon = tbl.LogOnInfo
            logon.ConnectionInfo = ci
            tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logon)
        Next
        '
        ' Set export options.
        '
        ExportOptions = rpt.ExportOptions
        ExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
        ExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
        DiskFileOptions.DiskFileName = "C:\DataBase\Test.pdf"
        ExportOptions.DestinationOptions = DiskFileOptions
        '
        ' Export report.
        '
        rpt.SetParameterValue("ShipmentID", ShipmentID)
        rpt.SetParameterValue("ShippingLocation", ShippingLocation)
        
        rpt.Export() 'here error threw 
        rpt.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw
    End Try

End Sub

How to solve it ??? Do we need to set the db connection once again with Crystal Report??
I have installed the CR - CR13SP32MSI64_0-80007712
and CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_9 as well in my machine. Still it shows the error.
My lap is having Win10 64 bit OS.
